# Pushing absolute div element over 100% makes the entire container shift over

Tags: css, html, css-position

I'm having a weird issue. I've got a 'container' div encapsulating the content of my page, and inside of that I have three other div blocks.

The three div blocks inside of the container are fit to exactly 100% of the screen height, but when I push the third div block a bit past the 100% mark, the entire 'container' div shifts over to the left by about 20px.

Here's is my jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Y7y5R/

By changing:

```
#secondaryContent{
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   top: 50%;
   height: 50%;
   background-color: red;
}
```

to

```
#secondaryContent{
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   top: 60%;
   height: 50%;
   background-color: red;
}
```

you will see what I am trying to explain. I'm just looking for an explanation on why this is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are using absolute positioning, which removes elements from the normal flow. With this positioning, setting `height:100%` will **not** contain the elements.

You had:

```
html, body {
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

This will only hide the overflow of things on the x axis. The problem you are seeing (x-axis), 'pushes' the third `div` vertically.. therefore setting `overflow-x` is useless.

You could simply set:

```
html, body {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

This will hide the issue, as you will no longer see the shift. As for the reason you are seeing the shift, `100% != 110%`. You would have to recalculate the positioning.

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Y7y5R/1/)